# Haar cascade tracking of multiple balls

Tags: python, opencv, cascade

I created haar cascade which is able to track all balls in the image, then I tried to train it to track only green balls but its not working. Is it even possible to track only balls with certain color?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Haar features* are only based on **pixels intensity**. That's why the input image is converted to a grayscale image before being processed (as shown in this Python [tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d7/d8b/tutorial_py_face_detection.html)).

So the answer is **no**, you can't track only balls of certain color with an Haar Cascade Classifier.

Instead, you could try the approach explained [here](http://answers.opencv.org/question/124344/combine-a-haar-cascade-with-color-detection/?answer=124347#post-id-124347).